# Is it possible to program an ESP8266 12F using an Arduino Nano?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-nano

I just got my ESP8266, but I am unable to program it. Since it can't be connected to via USB, I was wondering if I can program it using an Arduino or perhaps use it as a shield for an Arduino Nano. I haven't been able to find a good guide online. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't connect via usb?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can program it with Arduino but its a bit complex that way. You will need a separate Linear Regulator with Adjustable Output to get it hooked up with the Arduino.
 Its way better to have an FTDI adapter to program it.

But if you still want to know, there is a tutorial below,

Upload Bareminimum sketch so that no program is running on the Arduino.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to program an ESP8266 12F using an Arduino Nano?

Yes, but it is much easier to use a FTDI for USB-to-Serial adaptation. Two buttons are also needed to activate the ESP8266 programming mode.

Cheers!

Comment: Actually that tutorial has some fairly serious problems.  It claims the regulator is an "LM1117" but neglects to mention that this part comes in various voltage ratings, and it neglects to mention capacitors required by the regulator data sheet.  The author might have gotten away with it using the part they had on hand, but it is not good guidance.

Comment: Could you suggest a link to a better tutorial? Please feel free to update.